# Need an input control program in python

Tags: python, windows, input, mouse

I want to create a program that catches mouse clicks, no matter in which application it is sent to. Then it has to simulate twenty mouse clicks in one second. I am quite new to Python, and I am not really understanding much, but I've searched in several sites and I assembled this code:

```
import time
import ctypes
import pyHook
import pythoncom
MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001 # mouse move
MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000 # absolute move
MOUSEEVENTF_MOVEABS = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE + MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE

MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002 # left button down 
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004 # left button up 
MOUSEEVENTF_CLICK = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP

def click(vdf):
    hm.UnhookMouse()
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_CLICK, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(1)
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_CLICK, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    hm.HookMouse()
    return 0

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.SubscribeMouseAllButtonsDown(click)
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
os.system("pause")
```

This is just a sample. It has to generate 2 mouse clicks with a second interval. When I start it however, that's what comes out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Valjo\Desktop\hack.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyHook
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pyHook\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from HookManager import *
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pyHook\HookManager.py", line 1, in<module>
    import cpyHook
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pyHook\cpyHook.py", line 9, in <module>
    new_instancemethod = new.instancemethod
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'instancemethod'
```

And it creates some file named `new.pyc`...

*Any ideas how to fix it?* Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're generating events in the event handler for the event that produces an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh yeah! You are right. Only I have to unhook the mouse before generating the clicks then hook it again! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems one of your files is named `new.py` and it shadows `new` module from Python's stdlib. Write in your script: `import new; print new.__file__`. What is the output?

Comment: None. It doesn't print anything!

Comment: Maybe it has something to deal with the fact that the event handling function holds one argument, but never uses it? Or it is a module error?

Comment: I've seen what it prints now, it is D:\Python2.7\lib\new.pyc !

Comment: Check this question, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007847/python-program-that-plays-flash-games-for-me/4007917#4007917

Answer (score 1):

Use eventghost: http://www.eventghost.org/

- Open source
- You can write plugins in Python
- You can catch lots of different events (you can even capture raw HID devices)
- You can make it run/do anything you could normally do with Python

Comment: I don't really need this. J.F. Sebastien already helped me to fix my code.